# Flutter Cannot sign app - everything fails

Tags: flutter, signing

I have previously published apps on the store.

I am trying to use my regular keystore, as there first option here (or any of them) using my key.jks file, that I have used before with 0 issues.

[image]

Now it says for each option:

1. The private key was not properly encrypted or is not a type of key we support.
2. Requires PEPK tool which I have never used, so this cannot be right.
3. Says to use a key, but does even tell you what command you are supposed to use.  Look at this pile of poop:

[image]

Edit: The "this code" link above downloads a .jar file on it's own with no instructions on how to use it.

What am I supposed to do here?   I am getting really sick of the amount of time I have to spend sorting out how broken the back end is.   It literally takes me the same amount of time to write my applications as it takes to fix everything that is wrong with what should be the simplest part:  making them available.